# PHP regex find and replace with new string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which contains:

```
[quote name="username" url="/t/44223/topics-name#post_734738"]
```

I want to write a php regex which will find all the occurrence of this string and find the post number (ex. 734738) and later replace the whole thing with:

```
[quote=username;new post number based on 734738]
```

Requirements:

1. Only URL which starts with '/t/' and ends with '#post_{number}'.
2. By 'new post number based on 734738' means this will be my custom post number which I will generate from database.

Please help me out. Thanks.

## Final Answer:

This is the final answer in case anyone needs this :)

```
$string = '[quote name="user343I_nsdfdame" url="/t/44223/topics-name#post_734738"]What is your name?[/quote][quote name="username" url="/t/45454/topics-name#post_767676"]Test string[/quote]The quick brown fox....';

if(preg_match_all("/\[quote name=\"([^\"]*)\" url=\"\/t\/[^#]*#post_([0-9]*)\"\]/", $string, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        if(preg_match("/\[quote name=\"([^\"]*)\" url=\"\/t\/[^#]*#post_([0-9]*)\"\]/",$match, $reg)) {
            $new = "[quote=".$reg[1].";".$reg[2]."]"; // I have changed $reg[2] according to my need.
            $string = str_replace($match, $new, $string);
        }   
    }
}

echo $string;
```

Output:

```
[quote=user343I_nsdfdame;734738]What is your name?[/quote][quote=username;767676]Test string[/quote]The quick brown fox....
```

Comment: Where's the code you've tried?

Comment: Actually I have zero knowledge about php regex. So I am hoping for someone to write me a regex.

Comment: Well you should at least make an effort to research it and try something before expecting someone to divy up their time writing your code for free.

Comment: Actually I was studying regex and honestly I am having fun. Really amazing thing. Sorry, next time I will study first and post question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$string = '[quote name="username" url="/t/44223/topics-name#post_734738"]';
$new = "";
if(preg_match("/\[quote name=\"([^\"]*)\" url=\"\/t\/[^#]*#post_([0-9]*)\"\]/",$string,$reg)) {
    $new = "[quote=".$reg[1].";new post number based on ".$reg[2]."]";
}
echo $new;
```

Output is:

```
[quote=username;new post number based on 734738]
```

Comment: your coder is correct but for multiple occurrence I think I have to use 'preg_match_all' function. Anyway thanks :)